# Bash within a bash not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I used this:

https://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/

to create a nice and simple kiosk compute. One issue I had was the need to login to the kiosk page and I chose to overcome this with xdotool. I created a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0
sleep 3
xdotool type 'username'
sleep 3
xdotool key Tab
sleep 3
xdotool type 'password'
sleep 3
xdotool key Return
sleep 3
xdotool key Tab
sleep 3
xdotool key Return
```

and when launched from the command line it works great, however when I add that same code to the script that launches chrome on startup:

```
#!/bin/bash
xset -dpms
xset s off
openbox-session &
start-pulseaudio-x11

google-chrome --test-type --kiosk  --no-first-run  --ignore-certificate-errors 'url'

sleep 30
export DISPLAY=:0
sleep 3
xdotool type 'username'
sleep 3
xdotool key Tab
sleep 3
xdotool type 'password'
sleep 3
xdotool key Return
sleep 3
xdotool key Tab
sleep 3
xdotool key Return
```

it fails. I also tried to just execute the working command:

```
#!/bin/bash
xset -dpms
xset s off
openbox-session &
start-pulseaudio-x11


google-chrome --test-type --kiosk  --no-first-run  --ignore-certificate-errors 'url'

./login.sh
```

that fails too. Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I am a web guy with very little linux knowledge so this could be something very stupid but Im learning...

Comment: First of all, I'd be you I would **never** use `rm -rf` without using `if [ "$?" = 0 ] then ... fi` just after. This prevents you from doing something unexpected.

Comment: the loop makes sense, I took it out and tried this:

    #!/bin/bash
    xset -dpms
    xset s off
    openbox-session &
    start-pulseaudio-x11

    google-chrome --test-type --kiosk  --no-first-run  --ignore-certificate-errors 'url'
   
    sleep 30
    export DISPLAY=:0
    sleep 3
    xdotool type “username"
    sleep 3
    xdotool key Tab
    sleep 3
    xdotool type “password"
    sleep 3
    xdotool key Return
    sleep 3
    xdotool key Tab
    sleep 3
    xdotool key Return

still no response. Browser opens but no key commands.

Comment: Also, "it fails" is too vague. Please, paste the error message, or describe the expected and observed behaviour.

Comment: There are no errors in the log. It opens the webpage as expected but no key commands are executed. Basically it appears to stop executing after launching chrome. (also the " are ' in the script, somewhere along the line it got changed in my notes.)

Answer (score 1):

I just had to add & after the google-chrome and specify entire address....so:

```
google-chrome --test-type --kiosk  --no-first-run  --ignore-certificate-errors 'url'&
/opt/login.sh
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: To state it explicitly, for the benefit of future readers: you had to start `google-chrome` _asynchronously, in the background_, using the post-positional [control operator `&`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02), so that the rest of your script would continue executing.